# SharePoint Issue Tracker - auto approve if in a group and auto set of 'source'?

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint 2007

I've setup and Issue Tracker as a quick ticket system.   I gave everyone in all the internal domains access to view the page and to create items, then I made a list of team members and gave them rights to edit/delete items (etc).

The Issues all have a "pending/approved" column and a radio button selection on the new issue form to choose between "internal" or "external" issue (if a core team member created the issue or someone from the outside).

I'm not sure if it's possible but I've been trying to figure out how auto set the internal/external radio selection (if the person creating the issue is on the list of core team members - auto set 'source' to 'internal' else 'external'.   And I've also been trying to figure out how to auto-approve items if they are internal items.

So, if someone on the team member group list creates an issue it should be automatically have it's source set to "internal" and it should be auto-appoved.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use SharePoint Designer like this:

1. Customize the NewForm.aspx to remove the internal/external field altogether from the initial creation.
2. Create a new workflow on the list that automatically starts when a new item is created.
3. Use the condition "Created by a specific person" and choose the created by to be the Team Members group
4. Set the action to "Update List Item" and set the Internal/External field to internal
5. Add an additional action of "Set Content Approval Status" and set it to Approved
6. Click the "Add 'Else If' Conditional Branch" link
7. Add an action for the Else condition of "Update List Item" and set the Internal/External field to external

The first step is just for appearance *(since regardless of what they choose you will be setting it for them automatically)*. The workflow will take care of auto setting your fields based on the creator's group membership.

Comment: That sounds really easy Thanks.  I'm having trouble following the instructions though (maybe I'm missing a good template for this?).  I get the choice of 5 different workflow templates and none of them look like they have the right options.  For example, the "approval" template has no place for logic conditions.  Thanks!

Comment: sorry - duh.  SharePoint Designer.   Trying to go through it now.

Comment: I didn't think step 3 would work because you can't assign a group to the "Created by a specific person" condition

Answer (score 0):

You need an event receiver that fires on ItemAdded (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx) that sets both Source depending on the user that posted the issue and approves if source is internal.